# Need: In memory object database, transactional safety, indices, LINQ, no persistence

Tags: linq

Anyone an idea?

The issue is: I am writing a high performance application. It has a SQL database which I use for persistence. In memory objects get updated, then the changes queued for a disc write (which is pretty much always an insert in a versioned table). The small time risk is given as accepted - in case of a crash, program code will resynclocal state with external systems.

Now, quite often I need to run lookups on certain values, and it would be nice to have  standard interface. Basically a bag of objects, but with the ability to run queries efficiently against an in memory index. For example I have a table of "instruments" which all have a unique code, and I need to look up this code.... about 30.000 times per second as I get updates for every instrument.

Anyone an idea for a decent high performance library for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an in-memory SQLite database (:memory) with [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).